# How to power PCA9685

Tags: pi-4, power, power-supply, servo

I am using the RP 4B and am trying to control a servo with the PCA9685. Unfortunatelly I am very new to all that and therefore I don't know which specific components I need to power it up. I bought a power chord and an adapter recommended from a website, but those weren't even compatible with each other.. (guess it was outdated) So I would be really glad if someone could name me some specific products I can use to make the PC9685 run. Maybe even an Amazon-Link would be awesome. Thanks ahead!

Comment: Shopping requests are off-topic on this site.  What sort of servo?  Why not control it direct from the Pi?

Comment: Ah, Lada Ada is my friend: https://www.adafruit.com/product/815.

Comment: @joan Well idk where else to ask. it's the mg995. I can't control it from the Pi bcs RPi.GPIO makes it just shake and I've already tried to use pigpio but didn't made it work.

Comment: pigpio will work.  You need to specify the GPIO number for the control line.